# Bash, regular expressions, parameter to file

Tags: bash

I have an assignment in which I have to send to a file an unlimited list of parameters, the file will have to print the strings which are repeated in the following way:

> NumNumNumCharCharChar...

- Num- number
- Char-character

**every three following numbers are the same, as well as the three next characters,** then another three numbers and then another three characters.
The string must start with numbers and end with characters in a repeated way.

In order to solve this question, you may use *only* `grep`/`egrep` — up to you, which means that the solution is in regular expressions..

OK, this is what I thought to do for the egrep:

```
egrep "^([0-9][0-9][0-9][a-b][a-b][a-b])\1*$"
```

Comment: What have you tried? It's your assignment, so _you_ need to come up with something. You'll get help if you show that you've put effort into it yourself beforehand.

Comment: What do you call a "character" here? Lowercase ASCII-only letter, ASCII-only letter whether lowercase or uppercase, other? Hint: use backreferences.

Comment: lowercase ASCII ONLY (a-z)

Comment: Do you require repetition (111aaa222bbb) or just characters in the same class (123abc456def)? Do you have to have equal numbers of both groups? That is, is `123abc123` an accepted match?

Comment: i do need repetition (111aaa222bbb)

Comment: Once again, what have you tried?

Comment: Is each string on a separate line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt is almost correct. The backreference `\1` will require repetitions of the matching string, not the matching pattern. Allow the pattern to repeat instead. Inside the repetitions, you do want backreferences:

```
egrep '^(([0-9])\2{2}([a-z])\3{2})+$' file
```

As a shell scripting tweak, I switched to single quotes (double quotes are less safe) and I extended the lowercase class to `[a-z]`. Note that the outer parentheses are group 1, so the backreferences to the inner parenthesized expressions will be `\2` and `\3`.